# Access GAPI authorization in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, oauth-2.0, google-api

Using the following JavaScript code, I authorized myself to access the Google API. I use that to use JavaScript to set the contents of a span element. But, I also need to save this data into a MySql database with PHP. How can I access the authorization from JavaScript in PHP code? Here is the JavaScript code:

```
// Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
var CLIENT_ID = "XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
var API_KEY = "XXX";

// Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];

// Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
// included, separated by spaces.
var SCOPES = "https://mail.google.com/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";

/**
 *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
 */
function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.load("client:auth2", initClient);
}

/**
 *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
 *  listeners.
 */
function initClient() {
  gapi.client.init({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
    scope: SCOPES
  }).then(function () {
    document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getBasicProfile().getEmail();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could authorize users via php. Besides, if it really necessary to do it so, you can send data with AJAX request.

Comment: The problems are, I don't want to authorize the user twice, and I need to do stuff with the authorization in both JavaScript and PHP on the same page.